# what is the meaning of "improve away"?

Tags: meaning, archaic-language

what is the meaning of "improve away"?

It is the presentation of a principle
inherent in man's nature, a principle which his wisdom has **improved
away** until it is wellnigh eliminated altogether, but which crops out again
and again in spite of him —the principle of Spirit as opposed to Matter, of
Soul acting and existing independently of the body which enshrines it.
Long years of denial of aught but the properties of matter have landed
the chief lights of modern science in pure Materialism. To them,
therefore, this Spiritualism is a portent and a problem. It is a return to
superstition; a survival of savagery; a blot on nineteenth century
intelligence. Laughed at, it laughs back; scorned, it gives back scorn for
scorn.

source:http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks03/0301051h.html _ hos by acd

Comment: To (verb) away can mean to remove or eradicate using the action of the verb - e.g. scrub, wash, wipe away dirt. Human beings have so 'improved' their nature that the principle of 'Spirit' has been 'improved away'.

Comment: It's a deliberately *facetious* usage implying the author doesn't see any real "improvement".

Comment: Hence my quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Away](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/away) in the sense of:

> continuously or repeatedly, or in a busy way:
>
> - I was still writing away when the exam finished.
> - Chris has been working away in the garden all day.
> - We were chatting away at the back and didn't hear what he said.

(Cambridge Dictionary)

The meaning of  the sentence is:

*a principle which his wisdom has continually improved until it is wellnigh eliminated altogether.*

Comment: I think this sense from that same Cambridge definition is the right one: "gradually until mostly or completely gone", e.g. "The music faded away", as in Michael Harvey's comment above.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty - that would make sense with verbs like face, move etc. but improve?

Comment: I think so. Not like "move away", but more like "scrub away", including the result of disappearance. With "improve", it's a creative use, but it fits the sense of the sentence. Actually, on further thought, it could be either sense.

Comment: Yet further reflection convinces me that my original comment was correct. All the examples you quote are intransitive, while the OP  clearly has a transitive use: "a principle..[which] his wisdom has improved away". It's a use analogous to "worn away", "scrubbed away", etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example.

> "Poor things! their ancient communal life and interests, with all the
> local questions and politics which belonged thereto, and even to a
> great extent the religious festivals, have been **improved away** ;"

-From Adam's Peak to Elephanta By Edward Carpenter 1910

- https://books.google.lk/books?id=PHEYm84jcU4C&lpg=PA83&pg=PA83#v=onepage&q&f=false

So what does this mean? continually improved doesn't suits here, right? I think it says communal life is disturbed as the sentence starts as "poor things".